# Template not in directory

Tags: eclipse, maven

I've created my own archetype that imitates how Eclipse's new project wizard (the way Eclipse does it by default when not using Maven). It sets up a plain Java project in its subdirectory structure without the *main/java* and *test/java* subdirectories that are traditional in Maven/old Java.

*archetype.xml*:

```
<archetype>
  <id>java-project</id>
  <allowPartial>true</allowPartial>
  <sources>
    <source>src/App.java</source>
  </sources>
  <resources>
    <resource>src</resource>
  </resources>
  <testSources>
    <source>test/AppTest.java</source>
  </testSources>
  <testResources>
    <resource>test</resource>
  </testResources>
</archetype>
```

The archetype builds and installs successfully, but when used to create a new project,

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.etretatlogiciels \
        -DarchetypeArtifactId=java-project \
        -DarchetypeVersion=1.0 \
        -DgroupId=com.funk \
        -DartifactId=funk-project \
        -DarchetypeRepository=/home/russ/.m2/repository
```

it gives this BUILD FAILURE error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate
>   (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Template 'src/App.java' not
>   in directory 'src/main/java' -> [Help 1]

I'm trying to determine why it sounds like it's trying to use the more complicated, traditional Maven filesystem structure (*src/main/java/.../App.java*), when I've explicitly tailored the *achetype.xml* file to create

```
src/.../App.java
test/.../AppTest.java
```

i.e.: the simpler way Eclipse does it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you properly put the file `App.java` in the directory `src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/java` resp. `src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src`?

Comment: @thomas: Yes, I did do that.

Answer (score 1):

Defining custom archetype-metadata.xml file in the META-INF/maven helped me

```
<fileSets>
<fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true" encoding="UTF-8">
  <directory>src/directory>
  <includes>
    <include>**/*.java</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
```

http://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-descriptor/archetype-descriptor.html